# SalesForce Security issues with the API login

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl, salesforce

I have a user account on a clients Salesforce. These credentials are used on our Web service to connect and upload data to that clients Salesforce account.

However I have found that only my PC will allow the logging in to the API, this is not ideal as I need to have multiple users logged in using the same account and on different PC's in our organisation.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my URL endpoints, the web server we are using does various unexpected things that I was not aware of  for security purposes.

I have since devised a workaround by dumping the data into a table and then using a console app to poll this table and transmit the data to salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

a review of their policy suggests that what you want to do is prohibited, however it seems that it should be possible. There is a way to lock the account to the ip that created and perhaps that is being used as a default. please have a look here and see if it applies to your situation. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_sessions.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I have admin access, and they do not have that setting enabled, according to the API docs I have found multiple login's are accepted, but I think each one requires a different security token, I just want to get rid of the security token if I can, otherwise things will get tricky

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, you need to append the Security Token to the password to allow API logins from IP addresses that aren't trusted. This is a fairly standard way of calling the API. Note that changing the password will also change the Security Token.

The alternative to using the security token is to add the IP addresses of the Server making the API calls to the Trusted IP ranges.

```
Setup > Administration Setup > Security Controls > Network Access
```